# Laravel how to get data from a job?

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I got the Laravel queue (with Redis).  I need to get the job from this queue. I 'm trying to do:

```php
$queues = Queue::getRedis()->zrange('queues:confluence:delayed' ,0, -1);
foreach ($queues as $job) {
    $tmpdata = json_decode($job);
    $command = $tmpdata->data->command;
}
```

But in `$command` I got this string:

> "O:16:\"App\Jobs\TestJob\":8:{ s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000name\";s:5:\"12345\";s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";s:10:\"confluence\";s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";i:5;s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{} }"

```
> It does not seems like json or anything else (what I can parse to
> normal object/array). How can I get job data in this way?
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems I had same problem here: [Laravel 8 problem to unserialize command from payload (of failed job)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915523/laravel-8-problem-to-unserialize-command-from-payload-of-failed-job)

$command = unserialize($tmpdata->data->command); will not work because we have null in serialized string "\u0000" I used:

```
$str = str_replace('\u0000', ' ', $payload['data']['command']);
```

After this string fix I use:

```
$unserialized = unserialize($str, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
```

But this seems awful solution. It must be Laravel have something better to offer.

Answer (score 1):

The data you're seeing is serialized. You can unserialize it as such:

```
 $command = unserialize($tmpdata->data->command);
```

Though take care, and read the documentation for this command as it is a potential security risk: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php