# Laravel 8 problem to unserialize command from payload (in failed job)

Tags: laravel, serialization, unicode

I'm absolute beginner in Laravel and have problem.

I need to convert payload to formatted string.
This is payload from failed_jobs table:

**Raw payload get from failed_jobs table is:**

```
    {"retries":5,"data":{"command":"O:23:\"App\\Jobs\\SearchForEvent\":11:{s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000alert\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":4:{s:5:\"class\";s:16:\"App\\Models\\Alert\";s:2:\"id\";i:1;s:9:\"relations\";a:0:{}s:10:\"connection\";s:5:\"mysql\";}s:12:\"\u0000*\u0000startDate\";N;s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000endDate\";N;s:3:\"job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:10:\"middleware\";a:0:{}s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}","commandName":"App\\Jobs\\SearchForEvent"},"maxTries":null,"attempts":0,"uuid":"44543b2d-d724-443f-b1b9-8cd4c6eb9d6c","timeout":null,"tags":["App\\Models\\Alert:1"],"id":"44543b2d-d724-443f-b1b9-8cd4c6eb9d6c","retry_of":"5e268070-b783-419a-b111-313db95a8cf9","displayName":"App\\Jobs\\SearchForEvent","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","type":"job","pushedAt":"1617265554.6785","retryUntil":null,"maxExceptions":null,"delay":null,"timeoutAt":null}
```

I need output result like this:

**Payload:**

```
    retries: 5
    data:
      command: 
      {
         alert: {
           class: "App\Models\Alert",
           id: 1,
           relations: [
           ],
           connection: "mysql"
         },
         startDate: null,
         endDate: null,
         job: null,
         connection: null,
         queue: null,
         chainConnection: null,
         chainQueue: null,
         delay: null,
         middleware: [
         ],
         chained: [
         ]
    }
    commandName: App\Jobs\SearchForEvent
  maxTries: 
  attempts: 0
  uuid: 44543b2d-d724-443f-b1b9-8cd4c6eb9d6c
  timeout: 
  tags:
    0: App\Models\Alert:1
  id: 44543b2d-d724-443f-b1b9-8cd4c6eb9d6c
  retry_of: 5e268070-b783-419a-b111-313db95a8cf9
  displayName: App\Jobs\SearchForEvent
  job: Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call
  type: job
  pushedAt: 1617265554.6785
  retryUntil: 
  maxExceptions: 
  delay: 
  timeoutAt:
```

I have some solution, but looks its not good enough. Parsing payload is not a problem (but unserialize command is):

```
    public function findFailedJob(int $id): void
    {
        $this->failedJobObj = $this->model->find($id);
        $this->rawPayload = $this->failedJobObj->payload;
        $payloadArray = json_decode($this->failedJobObj->payload, 1);
        $this->manageCommand();
        $this->makeHumanReadablePayload($payloadArray);
    }
```

Parsing command is my problem. It contains null code "\u0000" and this make unserialize problematic. I've made pretty awfull method fro demo:

```
private function manageCommand()
{
    $payload = json_decode($this->failedJobObj->payload, true);
    if (! isset($payload['data']['command'])) {
        return '';
    }

    $str = str_replace('\u0000', ' ', $payload['data']['command']);
    $unserialized = unserialize($str, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    $this->command = print_r($unserialized, 1);
}
```

As result it returns:

**Command:**

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
(
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => App\Jobs\SearchForEvent
    [alert:protected] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
        (
            [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier
            [class] => App\Models\Alert
            [id] => 1
            [relations] => Array
                (
                )

            [connection] => mysql
        )

    [startDate:protected] => 
    [endDate:protected] => 
    [job] => 
    [connection] => 
    [queue] => 
    [chainConnection] => 
    [chainQueue] => 
    [delay] => 
    [middleware] => Array
        (
        )

    [chained] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Any idea for better solution for unserialise "command" containing '\u0000'?

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UURQA.png)

Comment: Why do you need to unserialize it ?

Comment: I really have no idea why there is a `\u0000`, in fact, there are 2. It is really strange, does that happen with all failed jobs or just some or for a specific Object ?