# How I can parse a failed job payload on laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am making the following command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use RuntimeException;

class FailedJobInfo extends Command
{
    protected $signature   = 'jobs:failed:info {job_id : Id of the failed job}';
    protected $description = 'Display detailed information regardind the failed job having id {job_id}';

    public function handle()
    {
        $config = config('queue.failed');

        if(empty($config) || empty($config['database']) || empty($config['table'])){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("
                A file in config folder named queue.php should exist. Also it should contain the following:
                'failed' => [
                    'database' => // database where the table will be created,
                    'table'    => 'failed_jobs', // Where the failed jobs will be stored
                ],

                Then run:

                php artisan help queue:failed-table
                php artisan migrate
            ");  
        }

        if(!Schema::connection($config['database'])->hasTable($config['table'])){
            throw new RuntimeException('Table '.$config['table'].' does not exist in database '.$config['database']);
        }

        $job_id = (int)$this->argument('job_id');

        if(empty($job_id) || $job_id < 0){
          throw new InvalidArgumentException('Job Id should be a positive integer');
        }

        $failed_job = DB::connection($config['database'])->table($config['table'])->where('id',$job_id)->limit(1)->select('*')->get();
        
        if(empty($failed_job)){
            throw new RuntimeException('Job has not been found');
        }
        
        $failed_job= $failed_job[0];

        $str = str_replace('\u0000', ' ', $failed_job->payload);        
        dump($str);
        $str = json_decode($str,1);
        dump($str);
        dump(unserialize($str, ['allowed_classes' => false]));
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to display information refarding a failed job and I try to unserialize the payload.

I the problem is that:

```
        dump(unserialize($str, ['allowed_classes' => false]));
```

Return `false` whereas `$str = json_decode($str,1);` fails to decode the json that payload is.

My payload has the following content:

```
{"job":"Illuminate\\\\Queue\\\\CallQueuedHandler@call","data":{"commandName":"App\\\\Jobs\\\\StoreIdsMonthlyReport","command":"O:30:\\"App\\\\Jobs\\\\StoreIdsMonthlyReport\\":5:{s:41:\\"\\u0000App\\\\Jobs\\\\StoreIdsMonthlyReport\\u0000store_ids\\";a:630:{i:0;s:4:\\"3840\\";i:1;s:4:\\"2101\\";i:2;s:4:\\"2547\\";i:3;s:4:\\"3257\\";i:4;s:3:\\"773\\";i:5;s:3:\\"165\\";i:6;s:4:\\"3654\\";i:7;s:4:\\"2530\\";i:8;s:2:\\"29\\";i:9;s:4:\\"3780\\";i:10;s:3:\\"134\\";i:11;s:5:\\"10593\\";i:12;s:4:\\"2048\\";i:13;s:4:\\"2572\\";i:14;s:5:\\"10400\\";i:15;s:4:\\"1475\\";i:16;s:4:\\"3555\\";i:17;s:4:\\"4305\\";i:18;s:4:\\"4106\\";i:19;s:4:\\"4104\\";i:20;s:4:\\"2865\\";i:21;s:4:\\"4363\\";i:22;s:4:\\"2589\\";i:23;s:4:\\"4060\\";i:24;s:4:\\"3273\\";i:25;s:5:\\"10687\\";i:26;s:3:\\"123\\";i:27;s:4:\\"4346\\";i:28;s:4:\\"2467\\";i:29;s:3:\\"348\\";i:30;s:4:\\"2265\\";i:31;s:4:\\"4337\\";i:32;s:4:\\"2545\\";i:33;s:4:\\"2566\\";i:34;s:4:\\"3480\\";i:35;s:4:\\"4320\\";i:36;s:4:\\"3663\\";i:37;s:2:\\"98\\";i:38;s:3:\\"149\\";i:39;s:4:\\"2724\\";i:40;s:4:\\"2947\\";i:41;s:4:\\"3871\\";i:42;s:5:\\"10474\\";i:43;s:4:\\"2654\\";i:44;s:4:\\"3925\\";i:45;s:4:\\"4125\\";i:46;s:4:\\"3790\\";i:47;s:2:\\"48\\";i:48;s:4:\\"4056\\";i:49;s:4:\\"4045\\";i:50;s:3:\\"161\\";i:51;s:4:\\"4369\\";i:52;s:3:\\"562\\";i:53;s:4:\\"2638\\";i:54;s:3:\\"369\\";i:55;s:5:\\"10581\\";i:56;s:4:\\"1466\\";i:57;s:3:\\"606\\";i:58;s:5:\\"10486\\";i:59;s:4:\\"3279\\";i:60;s:3:\\"295\\";i:61;s:4:\\"3879\\";i:62;s:4:\\"3287\\";i:63;s:3:\\"183\\";i:64;s:4:\\"1331\\";i:65;s:4:\\"4141\\";i:66;s:4:\\"3020\\";i:67;s:4:\\"8065\\";i:68;s:4:\\"1204\\";i:69;s:4:\\"4401\\";i:70;s:4:\\"3434\\";i:71;s:4:\\"4347\\";i:72;s:4:\\"3201\\";i:73;s:4:\\"1819\\";i:74;s:4:\\"3993\\";i:75;s:4:\\"3095\\";i:76;s:4:\\"3335\\";i:77;s:4:\\"2795\\";i:78;s:4:\\"3864\\";i:79;s:4:\\"2319\\";i:80;s:4:\\"1565\\";i:81;s:4:\\"2784\\";i:82;s:4:\\"4361\\";i:83;s:5:\\"10306\\";i:84;s:4:\\"2802\\";i:85;s:4:\\"4247\\";i:86;s:4:\\"2608\\";i:87;s:4:\\"2923\\";i:88;s:4:\\"3811\\";i:89;s:4:\\"4151\\";i:90;s:4:\\"1240\\";i:91;s:4:\\"3855\\";i:92;s:4:\\"1900\\";i:93;s:4:\\"2898\\";i:94;s:4:\\"9530\\";i:95;s:4:\\"3929\\";i:96;s:4:\\"4145\\";i:97;s:4:\\"3768\\";i:98;s:4:\\"1725\\";i:99;s:3:\\"224\\";i:100;s:4:\\"4399\\";i:101;s:1:\\"1\\";i:102;s:4:\\"1306\\";i:103;s:4:\\"2671\\";i:104;s:4:\\"4390\\";i:105;s:3:\\"786\\";i:106;s:4:\\"3404\\";i:107;s:4:\\"4394\\";i:108;s:4:\\"3252\\";i:109;s:4:\\"2540\\";i:110;s:4:\\"4335\\";i:111;s:5:\\"10559\\";i:112;s:4:\\"3851\\";i:113;s:5:\\"10578\\";i:114;s:4:\\"3068\\";i:115;s:4:\\"2578\\";i:116;s:3:\\"302\\";i:117;s:5:\\"10594\\";i:118;s:4:\\"2384\\";i:119;s:4:\\"4127\\";i:120;s:5:\\"10588\\";i:121;s:3:\\"128\\";i:122;s:4:\\"3911\\";i:123;s:3:\\"738\\";i:124;s:4:\\"4364\\";i:125;s:4:\\"3988\\";i:126;s:4:\\"3154\\";i:127;s:4:\\"3084\\";i:128;s:4:\\"2764\\";i:129;s:4:\\"3332\\";i:130;s:4:\\"1428\\";i:131;s:4:\\"4124\\";i:132;s:4:\\"2948\\";i:133;s:3:\\"877\\";i:134;s:3:\\"289\\";i:135;s:4:\\"4235\\";i:136;s:4:\\"3818\\";i:137;s:4:\\"1001\\";i:138;s:3:\\"121\\";i:139;s:4:\\"2129\\";i:140;s:4:\\"2922\\";i:141;s:5:\\"10570\\";i:142;s:4:\\"4307\\";i:143;s:4:\\"3160\\";i:144;s:4:\\"2847\\";i:145;s:4:\\"4250\\";i:146;s:4:\\"4227\\";i:147;s:4:\\"3915\\";i:148;s:4:\\"4140\\";i:149;s:4:\\"2831\\";i:150;s:3:\\"547\\";i:151;s:4:\\"3115\\";i:152;s:5:\\"10650\\";i:153;s:4:\\"2131\\";i:154;s:3:\\"615\\";i:155;s:4:\\"2639\\";i:156;s:4:\\"2725\\";i:157;s:4:\\"2145\\";i:158;s:4:\\"4006\\";i:159;s:4:\\"2620\\";i:160;s:5:\\"10607\\";i:161;s:4:\\"3950\\";i:162;s:4:\\"2912\\";i:163;s:4:\\"1222\\";i:164;s:4:\\"1619\\";i:165;s:3:\\"155\\";i:166;s:4:\\"4302\\";i:167;s:4:\\"3858\\";i:168;s:4:\\"1975\\";i:169;s:4:\\"2241\\";i:170;s:5:\\"10691\\";i:171;s:3:\\"666\\";i:172;s:4:\\"4133\\";i:173;s:4:\\"2405\\";i:174;s:4:\\"4130\\";i:175;s:4:\\"2369\\";i:176;s:4:\\"4209\\";i:177;s:4:\\"3347\\";i:178;s:4:\\"1712\\";i:179;s:4:\\"4195\\";i:180;s:4:\\"3938\\";i:181;s:4:\\"1797\\";i:182;s:4:\\"3901\\";i:183;s:4:\\"4318\\";i:184;s:4:\\"3292\\";i:185;s:4:\\"2010\\";i:186;s:4:\\"1761\\";i:187;s:4:\\"1622\\";i:188;s:4:\\"3309\\";i:189;s:5:\\"10533\\";i:190;s:3:\\"896\\";i:191;s:4:\\"2642\\";i:192;s:4:\\"3259\\";i:193;s:2:\\"58\\";i:194;s:4:\\"1134\\";i:195;s:5:\\"10488\\";i:196;s:1:\\"6\\";i:197;s:4:\\"2033\\";i:198;s:4:\\"2684\\";i:199;s:4:\\"2921\\";i:200;s:4:\\"2840\\";i:201;s:4:\\"2860\\";i:202;s:3:\\"629\\";i:203;s:3:\\"284\\";i:204;s:4:\\"3959\\";i:205;s:3:\\"157\\";i:206;s:4:\\"4019\\";i:207;s:4:\\"2575\\";i:208;s:4:\\"2944\\";i:209;s:5:\\"10487\\";i:210;s:4:\\"3349\\";i:211;s:4:\\"2990\\";i:212;s:4:\\"2742\\";i:213;s:5:\\"10473\\";i:214;s:4:\\"2065\\";i:215;s:3:\\"632\\";i:216;s:4:\\"1256\\";i:217;s:4:\\"2477\\";i:218;s:4:\\"4298\\";i:219;s:4:\\"2728\\";i:220;s:5:\\"10659\\";i:221;s:5:\\"10508\\";i:222;s:4:\\"3046\\";i:223;s:4:\\"3067\\";i:224;s:4:\\"3227\\";i:225;s:4:\\"3831\\";i:226;s:3:\\"127\\";i:227;s:4:\\"3704\\";i:228;s:4:\\"3327\\";i:229;s:4:\\"3244\\";i:230;s:4:\\"1060\\";i:231;s:4:\\"1792\\";i:232;s:5:\\"10524\\";i:233;s:4:\\"3600\\";i:234;s:5:\\"10652\\";i:235;s:4:\\"3210\\";i:236;s:4:\\"3101\\";i:237;s:5:\\"10480\\";i:238;s:3:\\"266\\";i:239;s:3:\\"532\\";i:240;s:4:\\"3805\\";i:241;s:2:\\"31\\";i:242;s:4:\\"5271\\";i:243;s:3:\\"206\\";i:244;s:4:\\"4352\\";i:245;s:3:\\"191\\";i:246;s:3:\\"988\\";i:247;s:4:\\"2449\\";i:248;s:5:\\"10535\\";i:249;s:4:\\"3684\\";i:250;s:4:\\"4288\\";i:251;s:5:\\"10681\\";i:252;s:4:\\"2653\\";i:253;s:3:\\"549\\";i:254;s:4:\\"2986\\";i:255;s:4:\\"2664\\";i:256;s:4:\\"2363\\";i:257;s:4:\\"3740\\";i:258;s:4:\\"2666\\";i:259;s:3:\\"218\\";i:260;s:3:\\"607\\";i:261;s:4:\\"2985\\";i:262;s:4:\\"3496\\";i:263;s:4:\\"1376\\";i:264;s:4:\\"4296\\";i:265;s:4:\\"4110\\";i:266;s:3:\\"771\\";i:267;s:5:\\"10666\\";i:268;s:3:\\"897\\";i:269;s:4:\\"4368\\";i:270;s:4:\\"3191\\";i:271;s:2:\\"47\\";i:272;s:4:\\"3683\\";i:273;s:3:\\"778\\";i:274;s:4:\\"2723\\";i:275;s:4:\\"2516\\";i:276;s:4:\\"3476\\";i:277;s:5:\\"10664\\";i:278;s:5:\\"10704\\";i:279;s:4:\\"3380\\";i:280;s:4:\\"1744\\";i:281;s:3:\\"112\\";i:282;s:5:\\"10516\\";i:283;s:2:\\"10\\";i:284;s:4:\\"4266\\";i:285;s:5:\\"10471\\";i:286;s:4:\\"2359\\";i:287;s:5:\\"10679\\";i:288;s:4:\\"2478\\";i:289;s:3:\\"469\\";i:290;s:5:\\"10509\\";i:291;s:3:\\"316\\";i:292;s:4:\\"4280\\";i:293;s:4:\\"1929\\";i:294;s:5:\\"10504\\";i:295;s:4:\\"3942\\";i:296;s:4:\\"4325\\";i:297;s:4:\\"4349\\";i:298;s:4:\\"2753\\";i:299;s:4:\\"4396\\";i:300;s:4:\\"2189\\";i:301;s:4:\\"4020\\";i:302;s:4:\\"4317\\";i:303;s:5:\\"10609\\";i:304;s:4:\\"2400\\";i:305;s:4:\\"3141\\";i:306;s:4:\\"2327\\";i:307;s:4:\\"4256\\";i:308;s:5:\\"10601\\";i:309;s:4:\\"3326\\";i:310;s:2:\\"51\\";i:311;s:4:\\"1298\\";i:312;s:3:\\"962\\";i:313;s:3:\\"651\\";i:314;s:4:\\"2749\\";i:315;s:3:\\"753\\";i:316;s:5:\\"10678\\";i:317;s:2:\\"61\\";i:318;s:4:\\"3012\\";i:319;s:4:\\"3746\\";i:320;s:5:\\"10503\\";i:321;s:4:\\"2132\\";i:322;s:4:\\"6583\\";i:323;s:4:\\"2446\\";i:324;s:4:\\"3412\\";i:325;s:4:\\"2137\\";i:326;s:4:\\"2658\\";i:327;s:3:\\"603\\";i:328;s:4:\\"2829\\";i:329;s:4:\\"1759\\";i:330;s:4:\\"1094\\";i:331;s:4:\\"3037\\";i:332;s:4:\\"4301\\";i:333;s:4:\\"2397\\";i:334;s:3:\\"863\\";i:335;s:4:\\"4051\\";i:336;s:4:\\"3498\\";i:337;s:4:\\"2721\\";i:338;s:5:\\"10692\\";i:339;s:5:\\"10667\\";i:340;s:3:\\"442\\";i:341;s:4:\\"2185\\";i:342;s:4:\\"1516\\";i:343;s:4:\\"1199\\";i:344;s:4:\\"3891\\";i:345;s:5:\\"10542\\";i:346;s:4:\\"3135\\";i:347;s:4:\\"3809\\";i:348;s:4:\\"4291\\";i:349;s:4:\\"2661\\";i:350;s:4:\\"2373\\";i:351;s:4:\\"2089\\";i:352;s:4:\\"1813\\";i:353;s:4:\\"4079\\";i:354;s:4:\\"3211\\";i:355;s:4:\\"1006\\";i:356;s:4:\\"1638\\";i:357;s:4:\\"4299\\";i:358;s:4:\\"2267\\";i:359;s:3:\\"476\\";i:360;s:3:\\"530\\";i:361;s:3:\\"408\\";i:362;s:4:\\"2989\\";i:363;s:5:\\"10543\\";i:364;s:5:\\"10515\\";i:365;s:4:\\"2379\\";i:366;s:4:\\"2894\\";i:367;s:4:\\"2851\\";i:368;s:4:\\"1020\\";i:369;s:4:\\"3187\\";i:370;s:4:\\"2663\\";i:371;s:4:\\"1983\\";i:372;s:4:\\"2406\\";i:373;s:4:\\"4067\\";i:374;s:4:\\"3914\\";i:375;s:4:\\"1821\\";i:376;s:4:\\"3605\\";i:377;s:5:\\"10507\\";i:378;s:4:\\"4180\\";i:379;s:4:\\"4323\\";i:380;s:3:\\"185\\";i:381;s:4:\\"4351\\";i:382;s:4:\\"3819\\";i:383;s:3:\\"118\\";i:384;s:4:\\"2075\\";i:385;s:4:\\"3106\\";i:386;s:4:\\"3813\\";i:387;s:4:\\"1814\\";i:388;s:3:\\"712\\";i:389;s:4:\\"5654\\";i:390;s:4:\\"1872\\";i:391;s:3:\\"636\\";i:392;s:2:\\"19\\";i:393;s:3:\\"162\\";i:394;s:3:\\"401\\";i:395;s:3:\\"411\\";i:396;s:4:\\"1096\\";i:397;s:4:\\"1172\\";i:398;s:4:\\"1939\\";i:399;s:4:\\"2239\\";i:400;s:4:\\"2439\\";i:401;s:4:\\"2972\\";i:402;s:4:\\"3861\\";i:403;s:4:\\"3899\\";i:404;s:4:\\"4211\\";i:405;s:4:\\"4251\\";i:406;s:5:\\"10492\\";i:407;s:5:\\"10529\\";i:408;s:5:\\"10531\\";i:409;s:5:\\"10606\\";i:410;s:4:\\"1943\\";i:411;s:4:\\"3350\\";i:412;s:4:\\"2744\\";i:413;s:4:\\"1104\\";i:414;s:5:\\"10637\\";i:415;s:4:\\"1192\\";i:416;s:4:\\"3699\\";i:417;s:4:\\"2918\\";i:418;s:4:\\"3423\\";i:419;s:3:\\"756\\";i:420;s:4:\\"3248\\";i:421;s:4:\\"4378\\";i:422;s:5:\\"10538\\";i:423;s:4:\\"3587\\";i:424;s:4:\\"3728\\";i:425;s:4:\\"3381\\";i:426;s:3:\\"541\\";i:427;s:4:\\"1527\\";i:428;s:4:\\"2249\\";i:429;s:4:\\"3240\\";i:430;s:4:\\"3274\\";i:431;s:3:\\"653\\";i:432;s:4:\\"1868\\";i:433;s:4:\\"1018\\";i:434;s:3:\\"367\\";i:435;s:4:\\"2165\\";i:436;s:4:\\"1180\\";i:437;s:5:\\"10513\\";i:438;s:4:\\"1593\\";i:439;s:3:\\"192\\";i:440;s:4:\\"3150\\";i:441;s:4:\\"3727\\";i:442;s:4:\\"3893\\";i:443;s:4:\\"3922\\";i:444;s:4:\\"2826\\";i:445;s:3:\\"520\\";i:446;s:5:\\"10520\\";i:447;s:3:\\"784\\";i:448;s:4:\\"4073\\";i:449;s:3:\\"891\\";i:450;s:4:\\"3290\\";i:451;s:4:\\"2212\\";i:452;s:5:\\"10654\\";i:453;s:4:\\"1729\\";i:454;s:4:\\"3243\\";i:455;s:4:\\"2612\\";i:456;s:4:\\"3035\\";i:457;s:5:\\"10684\\";i:458;s:5:\\"10640\\";i:459;s:5:\\"10490\\";i:460;s:2:\\"87\\";i:461;s:5:\\"10665\\";i:462;s:4:\\"4007\\";i:463;s:4:\\"3212\\";i:464;s:4:\\"1278\\";i:465;s:4:\\"3888\\";i:466;s:4:\\"4074\\";i:467;s:4:\\"2346\\";i:468;s:4:\\"4334\\";i:469;s:4:\\"4263\\";i:470;s:4:\\"3913\\";i:471;s:4:\\"2983\\";i:472;s:4:\\"4292\\";i:473;s:4:\\"3589\\";i:474;s:5:\\"10630\\";i:475;s:4:\\"1715\\";i:476;s:4:\\"2943\\";i:477;s:4:\\"4036\\";i:478;s:4:\\"1627\\";i:479;s:3:\\"449\\";i:480;s:4:\\"1924\\";i:481;s:4:\\"2105\\";i:482;s:4:\\"2567\\";i:483;s:4:\\"3693\\";i:484;s:4:\\"3711\\";i:485;s:4:\\"3550\\";i:486;s:4:\\"3459\\";i:487;s:4:\\"3446\\";i:488;s:4:\\"3142\\";i:489;s:4:\\"3072\\";i:490;s:4:\\"2933\\";i:491;s:4:\\"2761\\";i:492;s:4:\\"3962\\";i:493;s:4:\\"2672\\";i:494;s:4:\\"4021\\";i:495;s:4:\\"4120\\";i:496;s:4:\\"2266\\";i:497;s:4:\\"2133\\";i:498;s:4:\\"4232\\";i:499;s:3:\\"105\\";i:500;s:4:\\"1871\\";i:501;s:4:\\"1856\\";i:502;s:4:\\"4314\\";i:503;s:4:\\"1603\\";i:504;s:4:\\"1574\\";i:505;s:4:\\"1547\\";i:506;s:4:\\"1106\\";i:507;s:4:\\"1091\\";i:508;s:3:\\"812\\";i:509;s:2:\\"99\\";i:510;s:3:\\"723\\";i:511;s:5:\\"10511\\";i:512;s:3:\\"676\\";i:513;s:5:\\"10528\\";i:514;s:5:\\"10530\\";i:515;s:3:\\"626\\";i:516;s:3:\\"464\\";i:517;s:5:\\"10620\\";i:518;s:5:\\"10646\\";i:519;s:5:\\"10653\\";i:520;s:3:\\"407\\";i:521;s:3:\\"655\\";i:522;s:3:\\"623\\";i:523;s:4:\\"3421\\";i:524;s:4:\\"2713\\";i:525;s:4:\\"1587\\";i:526;s:3:\\"934\\";i:527;s:5:\\"10521\\";i:528;s:3:\\"422\\";i:529;s:3:\\"921\\";i:530;s:4:\\"2009\\";i:531;s:3:\\"761\\";i:532;s:4:\\"1668\\";i:533;s:5:\\"10683\\";i:534;s:4:\\"4374\\";i:535;s:5:\\"10517\\";i:536;s:4:\\"3583\\";i:537;s:4:\\"4354\\";i:538;s:4:\\"4386\\";i:539;s:5:\\"10621\\";i:540;s:4:\\"2438\\";i:541;s:4:\\"3110\\";i:542;s:5:\\"10577\\";i:543;s:3:\\"292\\";i:544;s:4:\\"2286\\";i:545;s:4:\\"1798\\";i:546;s:3:\\"578\\";i:547;s:4:\\"4214\\";i:548;s:3:\\"434\\";i:549;s:4:\\"1148\\";i:550;s:4:\\"2136\\";i:551;s:4:\\"3835\\";i:552;s:4:\\"4201\\";i:553;s:3:\\"376\\";i:554;s:4:\\"1052\\";i:555;s:4:\\"2781\\";i:556;s:4:\\"2281\\";i:557;s:5:\\"10603\\";i:558;s:3:\\"467\\";i:559;s:3:\\"506\\";i:560;s:4:\\"2614\\";i:561;s:4:\\"4327\\";i:562;s:4:\\"2429\\";i:563;s:3:\\"852\\";i:564;s:4:\\"2378\\";i:565;s:4:\\"2134\\";i:566;s:3:\\"428\\";i:567;s:4:\\"4181\\";i:568;s:5:\\"10685\\";i:569;s:4:\\"1546\\";i:570;s:4:\\"4168\\";i:571;s:4:\\"1391\\";i:572;s:4:\\"1343\\";i:573;s:4:\\"2171\\";i:574;s:4:\\"3709\\";i:575;s:4:\\"1101\\";i:576;s:4:\\"4065\\";i:577;s:5:\\"10499\\";i:578;s:4:\\"4063\\";i:579;s:3:\\"749\\";i:580;s:3:\\"732\\";i:581;s:3:\\"691\\";i:582;s:4:\\"3832\\";i:583;s:4:\\"3618\\";i:584;s:4:\\"3601\\";i:585;s:4:\\"2481\\";i:586;s:3:\\"642\\";i:587;s:4:\\"3276\\";i:588;s:4:\\"2667\\";i:589;s:5:\\"10589\\";i:590;s:5:\\"10591\\";i:591;s:3:\\"482\\";i:592;s:4:\\"3351\\";i:593;s:4:\\"3924\\";i:594;s:5:\\"10686\\";i:595;s:5:\\"10647\\";i:596;s:4:\\"4233\\";i:597;s:4:\\"4220\\";i:598;s:4:\\"1922\\";i:599;s:4:\\"4285\\";i:600;s:4:\\"1835\\";i:601;s:4:\\"1791\\";i:602;s:4:\\"4303\\";i:603;s:5:\\"10242\\";i:604;s:4:\\"6533\\";i:605;s:5:\\"10697\\";i:606;s:4:\\"1763\\";i:607;s:4:\\"4322\\";i:608;s:5:\\"10694\\";i:609;s:3:\\"445\\";i:610;s:4:\\"1610\\";i:611;s:4:\\"1184\\";i:612;s:3:\\"150\\";i:613;s:4:\\"2221\\";i:614;s:4:\\"2276\\";i:615;s:4:\\"2054\\";i:616;s:4:\\"1281\\";i:617;s:4:\\"2275\\";i:618;s:3:\\"959\\";i:619;s:3:\\"974\\";i:620;s:3:\\"568\\";i:621;s:4:\\"4379\\";i:622;s:4:\\"1200\\";i:623;s:4:\\"1904\\";i:624;s:5:\\"10183\\";i:625;s:5:\\"10498\\";i:626;s:3:\\"693\\";i:627;s:4:\\"3793\\";i:628;s:3:\\"955\\";i:629;s:4:\\"1025\\";}s:10:\\"connection\\";N;s:5:\\"queue\\";N;s:5:\\"delay\\";N;s:6:\\"\\u0000*\\u0000job\\";N;}"}}
```

And my solution was based upon the following questions anbd answers:

- [Laravel 8 problem to unserialize command from payload (in failed job)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66915523/4706711)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66915599/4706711

So do you have any idea how I can bypass the problem. Upgrade is a no-go cause the system is critical as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse the retrieved payload you should do the following:

1. Replace `\"` with `"`
2. Replace Multiple occurencec of `\` with a single `\`
3. Replace `\\` with `\`
4. Repolace `\u0000` with space

Then Json Decode and [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the data->command key.

The code that doe this is:

```
   $str = str_replace('\\"', '"', $failed_job->payload);
        $str = preg_replace("/\\+/", '\\', $str);
        $str = str_replace("\\\\","\\",$str);
        $str = str_replace('\u0000', ' ', $str);      
        $str = json_decode($str,true,512,JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE);

        dump(unserialize($str['data']['command'],['allowed_classes' => false]));
```

Resulting the following command:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use RuntimeException;

class FailedJobInfo extends Command
{
    protected $signature   = 'jobs:failed:info {job_id : Id of the failed job}';
    protected $description = 'Display detailed information regardind the failed job having id {job_id}';

    public function handle()
    {
        $config = config('queue.failed');

        if(empty($config) || empty($config['database']) || empty($config['table'])){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("
                A file in config folder named queue.php should exist. Also it should contain the following:
                'failed' => [
                    'database' => // database where the table will be created,
                    'table'    => 'failed_jobs', // Where the failed jobs will be stored
                ],

                Then run:

                php artisan help queue:failed-table
                php artisan migrate
            ");  
        }

        if(!Schema::connection($config['database'])->hasTable($config['table'])){
            throw new RuntimeException('Table '.$config['table'].' does not exist in database '.$config['database']);
        }

        $job_id = (int)$this->argument('job_id');

        if(empty($job_id) || $job_id < 0){
          throw new InvalidArgumentException('Job Id should be a positive integer');
        }

        $failed_job = DB::connection($config['database'])->table($config['table'])->where('id',$job_id)->limit(1)->select('*')->get();
        
        if(empty($failed_job)){
            throw new RuntimeException('Job has not been found');
        }
        
        $failed_job= $failed_job[0];

        $str = str_replace('\\"', '"', $failed_job->payload);
        $str = preg_replace("/\\+/", '\\', $str);
        $str = str_replace("\\\\","\\",$str);
        $str = str_replace('\u0000', ' ', $str);      
        $str = json_decode($str,true,512,JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE);

        dump(unserialize($str['data']['command'],['allowed_classes' => false]));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the unserialized data is an incomplete class.